# Django Model Factory get or create

Tags: django, django-models, factory-boy

I have a Django Model defined like below:

```
    class CustomModel(models.Model):
        column = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

Define a Factory for the model

```
from factory_boy import DjangoModelFactory
class CustomModelFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    
    column = 'V1'

FACTORY_FOR = CustomModelFactory()
```

How do i make sure that factory implements get_or_create instead of a create everytime?

Does anyone know how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to implement this is by structuring your Factory class as follow:

```
class CustomModelFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        django_get_or_create = ('column',)
    column = 'V1'

FACTORY_FOR = CustomModel
```

Comment: Does anyone know how we can turn it off ? I mean we have existing `django_get_or_create` attribute and then we want to turn it off for some cases

Answer (score 10):

As per the factory docs: 
https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orms.html#factory.django.DjangoOptions.django_get_or_create

They way to use get_or_create instead of create is to add "FACTORY_DJANGO_GET_OR_CREATE" with the list of fields which will be used for the get:

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'myapp.User'  # Equivalent to ``model = myapp.models.User``
        django_get_or_create = ('username',)
```

so in your example this would look like this:

```
    class CustomModelFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
        class Meta:
            model = CustomModel
            django_get_or_create = ('column',)
```

Comment: note that this will fail if you go and override `_create` like I did 